# Is textarea line break value always normalized to "\n" javascript string?

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks

Having a Windows system, I found out that a textarea's value consisting of one single line break is equal to the JavaScript string `"\n"`, and not `"\r\n"`:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("textarea").value === "\n"); // true
console.log(document.getElementById("textarea").value === "\r\n"); //false
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10">

</textarea>
```

Does it mean I should not worry about the `CRLF` vs `LF` issue while working with textarea values as their line breaks always normalized to the `"\n" === "\u{000A}"` string, so I can surely say that `lineBreakOnlyValue.length === 1` and fulfill such an assignment
`document.getElementById("textarea").value = "\n"` without thoughts about different systems line breaking addressing?

Was this behavior specificated in some way?

Comment: older versions of IE used `\r\n`, but now everyone (even window's notepad) has settled on `\n`, including pasting into. The only place where `\r\n` could creep in (afaik) is when a FileReader dumps the readAsBinaryString() result from a `\r\n`-using file value into the textarea.value. In short, no, you don't really need to worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the current HTML Standard, it says about the [textarea element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-textarea-element:concept-textarea-raw-value-8):

> The API value is the value used in the `value` IDL attribute, `textLength` IDL attribute, and by the `maxlength` and `minlength` content attributes. It is normalized so that line breaks use U+000A LINE FEED (LF) characters.
>
> [...] The algorithm for obtaining the element's API value is to return the element's raw value, with newlines normalized.

The normalization of newlines is described as [follows](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#normalize-newlines):

> To **normalize newlines** in a string, replace every U+000D CR U+000A LF code point pair with a single U+000A LF code point, and then replace every remaining U+000D CR code point with a U+000A LF code point.

### Comparison with other properties

While the `value` property is subject to this normalization, the `textContent`, `innerHTML`, ... properties are not.

A little demo:

```js
console.log("innerHTML", JSON.stringify(txt.innerHTML));
console.log("textContent", JSON.stringify(txt.textContent));
console.log("value", JSON.stringify(txt.value));
```

```html
<textarea id="txt">a&#13;&#10;b</textarea>
```

Comment: I wonder when we push the `enter` key while using a Windows system, will the `textarea` get `CRLF` as a raw value or the browser normalize it to `LF` itself?

Comment: I don't know. It certainly *could* do so, but since JavaScript cannot access the mutated raw value, but only the normalized value, it is transparent to JavaScript.